# Django primary key issue

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, composite-primary-key

I have a current model in Django app like below

```
class BasicInfo(models.Model):
    review_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to add one more column named sever and want to make review_id + server a composite key

```
class BasicInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    review_id = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    server = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('review_id', 'server'),)
```

when I am trying to apply the migrations I am getting this error

**$ python manage.py makemigrations review
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to basicinfo without a default; we can't do
that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this
   column)
2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
   Select an option:**

I have also tried to add a default value as 1 in the 'id' field but that doesn't work.
Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in local, delete your database and create a new one, you have data with existing rows, they need a default value but 1 is not unique so it will give you an error.

You can also delete only the table **BasicInfo**

Or you can set default value for your **review_id** :

```
review_id = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=None)
```

Comment: BasicInfo is a production table and it contains a lot of data, I cannot delete it. Is there any alternative to do this?

Comment: See my new answer

Comment: I am still getting the same error that I have mentioned above for column 'id'. 'review_id' is not causing any issue.

Comment: Yes because there is a flaw in your model, you should not add a PK afterward, your existing row need a unique identifier. 
Best thing to do is to keep your orignal PK and set the new one as and UUID